# Powershell files created outside of node_modules

Tags: npm, node-modules, package.json

Up until yesterday, whenever I installed a package (e.g. nodemon), they would be added to the node_modules dir. This morning, when I installed a bigger project, the powershell and cmd files were saved outside of that directory, in addition to a file without an extension. It looked like this:
[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TS2N.png)

Why is example, example.cmd and example.ps1 saved outside of node_modules?

Comment: How did you install them? Did the node/npm version change on your computer recently?

Comment: I simply wrote 'npm install __' in my command prompt. Nothing has changed as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question. I had accidentally messed around with the npm prefix. If this happens to you, go to the cmd prompt and type `npm set prefix C:/bin` and you should be alright :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution! :)